# SAP B1 Crystal Reports UFL Error in CRYSTAL REPORTS runtime (x64)

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

Using SAP Crystal Reports Designer, I developed a receipt for POS Printer. The report uses the UFL function that SAP B1 provides for example :
`SAPB1CRDecryptAndMaskGenerate ({RCT3.CrCardNum}, 0)`.

When viewed in SAP Crystal Reports Designer or even in Visual Studio, everything works. But when you run SAP Crystal Reports Runtime(x64) from under the SAP Business One (x64) client, an error occurs

> ```
> UFM 'u212com.dll' that implements this function is missing. 
> Error in File RCT10009
> {...}
> 8224_9372_{...}.rpt: 
> Error in formula CreditCardNumber: 
> 'SAPB1CRDecryptAndMaskGenerate ({RCT3.CrCardNum},0)'
> UFL 'u212com.dll' implements this function is missing.
> ```
>
> [image]